# Is it possible with Codename One to record microphone input and play it back simultaneously?

Tags: mobile, codenameone, audio-recording

I am using Codename One to record the microphone input and play it back to the connected earphones.

First of all if I record audio from mic to a file, and play it back when the recording is over, it works  as expected. That's why based on this [2014 question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/F1VhR4305Q8) I implemented 2 periodic tasks (timer and timertask), as long as 2 files : one for recording, one for playing. I set the periodic tasks period to values between 100 ms and some seconds, but the result was awful on the Android device. Indeed there were random gaps, it was not smooth at all, nor understandable.

I assume the overhead of writing to a file every period is too high and consequently is causing that behaviour. So [using proper high-level Codename One methods](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/capture/Capture.html) does not seem the way to go.

Then in the same question from 2014, the requester is suggesting to create an inputstream from the recording Media and use it as input for the playing Media. However the method `MediaManager.createMediaRecorderStream()` does not seem to be available anymore. I tried to use the file used to record audio as InputStream for the playing Media through `fs.openInputStream(recFilepath)` but it did not output any sound nor error on the device.

So my question is whether or not I can achieve my goal with bare Codename One or do I have to use the native interface ? Moreover Shai (in the 2014 above mentioned question) wrote that the second approach with `MediaManager.createMediaRecorderStream()` might work on some platforms : is the android platform among these, or only iOS platform was aimed at ?

Any help appreciated and sorry for not posting code since I cleared it as soon as an attempt did not appear to work. So I really messed up with my code which now is not doing anything I targetted initially.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall Android back in the day didn't support input stream for media and later only allowed capturing input directly as uncompressed WAV which makes full duplex usage impractical. This might have changed since as I recall they did some overhaul of their media libraries.

I'm not sure if this is exposed in our higher level code. Besides using native interfaces you can also help us improve Codename One by forking and hacking it e.g. this is the relevant code in the Android project:

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java#L2804-L2858

This is a contribution guide to Codename One, it covers running in the simulator but that's a good start: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html

You can test your changes on an Android device with instructions here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/debug-a-codename-one-app-on-an-android-device.html

Comment: Thanks @Shai for the input. It is indeed possible through native interface (at least for Android). How to do it is described in [my other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447441/how-to-test-an-android-native-code-snippet-with-codename-one/40454439#40454439). The latency is perceivable but the result is actually awesome. Regarding the contribution, you mean (re)creating a `createMediaRecorderStream()` method that returns a Stream that can be used by `createMedia()`or creating a method that directly plays back the mic input to the speakers ?

Comment: Yes, if you think we can improve the Android native methods used in our API implementation you can just fork the project and provide a better implementation of the native Android `createMediaRecorderStream`